# why variable used in except is removed

Tags: python, python-3.x

Why the variable used in the `except` statement is removed? I mean doing:

```
x = 0

try:
  x = 5/0
except ZeroDivisionError as x:
  pass

print(x)
```

I get `NameError: name 'x' is not defined` why this? Couldn't it work as with `def` or comprehensions where if there is a variable with same name of a variable in the enclosing function (or module) it is simply shadowed but not removed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is explained in [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.3/reference/compound_stmts.html#except) (parts in **[ ]** braces added by me):

> When an exception has been assigned using `as target` **[i.e. `as x` in your case]**, it is cleared at the end of the except clause. This is as if

```
except E as N:
    foo
```

> was translated to:

```
except E as N:
    try:
        foo
    finally:
        del N
```

> This means the exception must be assigned to a different name to be able to refer to it **[i.e. this name, `x` in your case]** after the except clause.

The reason for this is also stated:

> Exceptions are cleared because with the traceback attached to them, they form a reference cycle with the stack frame, keeping all locals in that frame alive until the next garbage collection occurs.

Answer (score 4):

The behavior is documented [here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-try-statement):

> When an exception has been assigned using as target, it is cleared at the end of the except clause.
>
> This means the exception must be assigned to a different name to be able to refer to it after the except clause.  Exceptions are cleared because with the traceback attached to them, they form a reference cycle with the stack frame, keeping all locals in that frame alive until the next garbage collection occurs.